# How do I install/get the libata kernel module to work?

Tags: boot, kernel, tpm

### Edit 1:

Running Ubuntu 18.04 here. I'm trying to set `/sys/module/libata/parameters/allow_tpm`, but to no avail.

`modinfo libata` tells me:

`modinfo: ERROR: Module libata not found.`

This is *after* running `apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)` followed by `apt update && apt upgrade` as well as a nice reboot.

### How I got to this point

I've tried editing `/sys/module/libata/parameters/allow_tpm` as root, but to no avail.

After doing `chmod 644` on the file and running `echo 1 > /sys/module/libata/parameters/allow_tpm` I get:

`-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error`

I've also tried adding this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.allow_tpm=1"`

to `/etc/default/grub`, followed by `update-grub` (as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485142/ata-trusted-commands-how-to-set-libata-allow-tpm) but that doesn't help.

Not even appending `libata.allow_tpm=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` has any effect.

### What I *really* want to do

I want to be able to run **sedutil**. But running `sedutil-cli --scan` tells me that

`The Kernel flag libata.allow_tpm is not set correctly`

What do I do?

Comment: `modinfo libata | fgrep parm` please I'm not in ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: @nobody it gives me `modinfo: ERROR: Module libata not found.`, which explains a bit...

Comment: did your system need libata? `lspci -nnk`  will show which modules for pci devices are in use.

Comment: @nobody It appears there that my SATA controller is running with the `ahci` kernel modules. But sedutil-cli requires me to set `libata.allow_tpm=1`...